# Discover Mac and iPhone device name

Tags: networking, mac, ios

I am writing some network discovery code but had a general networking question.  Using a Mac app like iNet gives me the name of iPhones, iPads and Macs even when they don't have a NetBIOS name, are not registered in DNS, and are not broadcasting any Bonjour services.   I am trying to figure out how they get the actual device name without resorting to any of these.  Is there another way to get a device name they could be using?   Of course sometimes the name is found using Bonjour or NetBIOS.   However, iNet and a few other network discovery apps often are able to discover the names even when these aren't available.

Comment: I do notice via WireShark that these devices do multi-cast their name via mDNS to port 224.0.0.251 even if they are not broadcasting any services.  Perhaps they aren't recognized by a Bonjour service browser because they don't have services but there are lower level mdns techniques to get the name.

Comment: Ok I have discovered that if you turn on iTunes Wi-Fi sync you can use a reverse mDNS lookup which returns the hostname  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309740/how-do-i-obtain-model-name-for-a-networked-device-potentially-using-bonjour.   But how to get the name when it's turned off like Fing and iNet do?